# Combining Video Swin Transformer and 2D-CNN Features for Video Captioning

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

For a video captioning model, I have sampled each video with 16 frames. I've employed a Video Swin Transformer to extract video features, resulting in a tensor of shape (batch_size, 768, 4, 7, 7). Additionally, I've used a 2D-CNN to extract frame-level features, resulting in a tensor of shape (batch_size, 16, 768). Now, I need to concatenate these two sets of features to create a combined representation with a shape like (batch_size, 16, 768 * 2) or similar, in order to use them effectively with a traditional transformer encoder. How can I achieve this concatenation for seamless integration into the model?